# Daily Level Forecast for 400 stores

Tags: time, time-series, forecasting

I am looking to run a forecast for next one year for 400 stores at once. But I am confused how to go about forecasting at one go. I am able to forecast for one store at a time but multiple stores are becoming a problem.

I have one row entry for each store. i.e.each row has store number and dates from Mar-2012 to Dec-2014.

Will using loop be helpful? or is there a way to model for all stores together?

Data:
Row: Store_Number
Column: historical daily Data for 2 years
 Any help around this would be helpful.

Currently I am using the below mentioned codes:

```html
tmdata<-read.csv(file.choose())
names(tmdata)
head(tmdata, n = 10)
str(tmdata)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
store<-tmdata$Store_nbr_31
plot(store)
store<-ts(tmdata$Store_nbr_31,frequency = 7)
store<-msts(tmdata$Store_nbr_31, seasonal_periods = c(7,365.25))
store<-msts(tmdata$Store_nbr_31, seasonal.periods = c(7,365.25))
plot.ts(store)
auto.arima(store)
atm.fir<-tbats(store)
atm.fc <- forecast(fit)
atm.fc <- forecast(atm.fir)
plot(atm.fc)
View(atm.fc)
atm.prs.dc<-decompose(atm.prs)
atm.prs.dc<-decompose(store)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Running the script in a loop for each store would certainly be a solution. Though without actual data it's hard to give a more concrete solution.

If you have 400 data files, one for each store, then you should also automate data file selection so that you don't have to manually select the file at each loop iteration.

Comment: Hi, I have only one file where the columns are store_number, 03-01-2013 03-02-2013 and so on.. until 12-31-2014. I just need to forecast sales for each store for next 1 year at a day level.

Comment: So you have one column for each date between March 2013 and December 2014? And one row per store? I recommend finding a clearer way of asking your question, or at the very least commenting your code so we can tell what's going on. Happy to help with a clearer question.

Comment: I am sorry for such an unclear entry. What you mentioned now is correct. Yes I have one column for each date between March 2013 and December 2014 and one row per store. This is my training data. Similiarly I have test data with numbers for Jan-15 to Mar-15. I need to forecast for remaining months in 2015 at a day level.